# styled-component wrongly interprets passed variable

Tags: reactjs, variables, styled-components

I'm using styled-components with Gatsby and I try to pass a variable "background" to the styled-component but somehow it doesn't get parsed properly.

Component:

```
const HeroWrapper = styled.section`
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  ${props => !props.small && `
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      117deg,
      rgba(218, 218, 218, 0.76) 56%,
      rgba(149, 27, 129, 0.66) 100%
    ),
    url(${props => props.background ? props.background : ' '});

    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  `}
`
```

The return of the function component in the gatsby component:

```
{!small && <HeroWrapper background={image.node.heroImage.asset.url} small={false}>{children}</HeroWrapper>}
```

Error Message in Chrome Code Inspector:

```
.hSZsaA {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    background-image: linear-gradient( 117deg, rgba(218,218,218,0.76) 56%, rgba(149,27,129,0.66) 100% ), url(function (props) { return props.background ? props.background :' '; });
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: calc(100vh - 165px);
}
```

It says `url(function (props) { return props.background ? props.background :' '; })`

The "small" var works fine. Somehow there's no output out of the "background" var.
What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You insert additional styles based on `small` with `${props => !props.small &&`  and then you have a tertiary expression after evaluating props again with `url(${props => props.background ? props.background : ' '});`.

My guess is that somewhere within one of those stacked function calls inside string literals, JavaScript just starts rendering a string.

Simplify your code. Evaluate the existence of `props.background` before passing it into styled component:

```
// Evaluate the teriary expression before passing it to styled component:
const styledBackground = image.node.heroImage.asset.url ? image.node.heroImage.asset.url : ' ';
{!small && <HeroWrapper background={styledBackground} small={false}>{children}</HeroWrapper>}


// ...

const HeroWrapper = styled.section`
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  ${props => !props.small && `
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      117deg,
      rgba(218, 218, 218, 0.76) 56%,
      rgba(149, 27, 129, 0.66) 100%
    ),
    url(${props => props.background});
    // ...
`
```

If this does not work simplify your evaluations with `&&` even further.

Comment: I managed to make it work with splitting the styled components into two wrapper, one big, one small and simplify it like you suggested. It worked!